# Request.JSON run with page load

Tags: json, mootools

http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Request.JSON

The JSON data load when you click on `load JSON Data` .

Is it possible to load this data when a page open ( a function like `onload` )

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent("domready",function(){
        var request = new Request.JSON({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            onRequest: function(){
                gallery.set('text', 'Loading...');
            },
            onComplete: function(jsonObj) {
                gallery.empty();
                addImages(jsonObj.previews);
            },
            data: { // our demo runner and jsfiddle will return this exact data as a JSON string
                json: JSON.encode(data)
            }
        }).send();

    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i didnt find `onClick` event then how i will replace it will `onload`

Comment: I got the json request code form the demo site, however, you need to modify the code by yourself to fit your site

Comment: i'm using the same but i dont understand how to load it when page run in browser

Comment: i'm not sure what do you mean...you mean you don't understand how ajax work? or you don't understand when the ajax request send to server? or otherwise

Comment: How should i load function like this 

**window.onload = function() {
  callhello();
};**

Comment: if you mean where to place, you could place it inside `<head></head>` with tag `<script type='text/javascript></script>`. Just like the content I update above